# Pattern matching key in Erlang maps

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, mapping, pattern-matching

I have a map of form shown below:

```
Map = #{#{country=>"India"} => #{rank => 1}}.
```

I am trying to match it as follows:

```
1. #{Key := V} = Map.
```

or

```
2. #{#{country := Country} := #{rank := Rank}} = Map.
```

But its not working for me. Any help as to how it can be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When matching key-value associations from maps the key expression must be an expression with literals or bound variables, see the [documentation of maps](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81479) (section **Maps in Patterns**).

The problem with a match expression like:

```
#{Key := V} = M.
```

Where `Key` is an unbound variable is that this matches *all* the key/value bindings in the map `M`, not a particular key/value. Same with the other match expression you tried, it can match several keys.

The correct way would be to fully specify the key here, like this

```
#{#{country => "India"} := V} = Map.
```